# How to draw fully connected graph link picture bellow in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]This picture represented a graph which is connected to every node. How to use tikz to draw this kind of graph?

[image]

Comment: Which drawing do you want? First or second? Btw, give a MWE .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is a`just-do-it-for-me` class of question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *not* your graph, but my recommended variant of it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,minimum size=.75cm,draw}]
    \node (a) at (0,2) {Goal};
    \node (c2) at (0,0) {$c_2$};
    \node (c3) at (2,0) {$c_3$};
    \node (c1) at (-2,0) {$c_1$};
    \node (a1) at (-1,-2) {$a_1$};
    \node (a2) at (1,-2) {$a_2$};
\end{scope}
\draw (a)--(c1)--(a1)--(c2)--(a2)--(c3)--(a)--(c2) (c1)--(a2) (c3)--(a1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- The size of the nodes should not be too big. Hence I use `minimum size=.75cm`.
- The nodes should be in circle shapes.
- You should not have all paths from a specific nodes connected. For instance, this is bad, in my opinion.

  [image]

  It is even worse if you want to add arrows.
- The nodes should have a good alignment. In this graph, they should be horizontally centered.
- Put node label in math mode, if they are something like *a*, *b*, *m*<sub>1</sub>, *n*<sub>2</sub>, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the pencil drawing, here is a sample code, which you can improve according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    draw   = black,
    minimum height = 2cm,
    minimum width  = 2cm
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) at (0,0) [squarenode] {Goal};
  \node[below=of a] (c2) [squarenode] {C2};
  \node[left=of c2] (c1) [squarenode] {C1};
  \node[right=of c2] (c3) [squarenode] {C3};
  \node[below=of c1] (a1) [squarenode] {A1};
  \node[below=of c2] (a2) [squarenode] {A2};

  \draw (a.south) to (c1.north);
  \draw (a.south) to (c2.north);
  \draw (a.south) to (c3.north);
  \draw (c1.south) to (a1.north);
  \draw (c1.south) to (a2.north west);
  \draw (c2.south) to (a2.north);
  \draw (c2.south) to (a1.north east);
  \draw (c3.south) to (a1.north);
  \draw (c3.south) to (a2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To understand the anchor points used, refer the diagram and code below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{dot/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    draw   = black,
    fill = black,
    minimum size = 0.2cm
}}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
        shape  = rectangle,
        draw   = black,
        minimum height = 10cm,
        minimum width  = 10cm
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) at (0,0) [squarenode] {};
  \node[label=a.center] at (a.center) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north] at (a.north) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south] at (a.south) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.east] at (a.east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.west] at (a.west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north east] at (a.north east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north west] at (a.north west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south east] at (a.south east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south west] at (a.south west) [dot] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to edit your answer a little: the second code is not compilable because `squarenode` is undefined, and you should use `tikz` as package name, _not_ `tikZ`!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a job for a TikZ matrix.

With `<matrix-name>-<row-number>-<column-number>` you can refer to matrix cells as nodes.

Here you find two versions of the graph, if you want the nodes to be squared, leave out the `circle` option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes={draw, circle},
        row sep=10ex,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
        mymatrix,
        column sep=3em
        ](mymatr){
        &\text{Goal}\\
        C_1 & C_2& C_3\\
        A_1 & A_2\\
    };
    \foreach \ind in {1,2,3} {
        \draw (mymatr-1-2) -- (mymatr-2-\ind);
        \draw (mymatr-3-1) -- (mymatr-2-\ind);
        \draw (mymatr-3-2) -- (mymatr-2-\ind);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
        mymatrix,
        column sep=1.5em
        ](mymatr){
        &&\text{Goal}\\
        C_1 && C_2&& C_3\\
        &A_1 && A_2\\
    };
    \foreach \ind in {1,3,5} {
        \draw (mymatr-1-2) -- (mymatr-2-\ind);
        \draw (mymatr-3-2) -- (mymatr-2-\ind);
        \draw (mymatr-3-4) -- (mymatr-2-\ind);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]